# Headphone Jack Issues

Tags: iphone, headphones

Alright, so at first I noticed the clicker on my headphones stopped working, but i thought it was a problem with the clicker. Turns out, it's actually just my phone. Somewhere down the line, the jack began just popping out of the port, seemingly at random. Later on I found out it only happens when the jack rotates at any degree (which happens surprisingly often if your phone's in your pocket). It only happens with headphones though, I've tested it on AUX cords and there's no issue with those whatsoever. My questions are why is this happening, what can I do to fix it, and if I can't fix it, who'd be able to?

Comment: If you have a spare set of earbuds do these give you get the same issue?

Comment: every other earbuds ive tried have had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Take a toothpick and carefully clean out any dirt or lint from the headphone jack. If that doesn't work, the headphone jack assembly needs to be replaced.

Comment: I'll definitely try the toothpick, I was hoping it wouldnt come down to replacing the whole assembly